# getting empty in http refer on facebook app

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which uses http refer, and I have made a Facebook application and I have given that site in Facebook application its working.
but there is error

when one of my client uses https on Facebook than  I am getting empty in http refer
but it works when client uses http on Facebook than I get the http refer.

is there any solution kindly share.
thanks in advance

Comment: It is common for referrers to get scrubbed when coming from SSL. Google does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Referrer property of a request is never guaranteed to exist. It is environment and browser specific.